# Trying to send redirect though jersey filter and the page won't refresh

Tags: java

Trying te redirect to an HTML page on my WebContent folder in my Java Dynamic Web project.
The web browser uses GET to get my request but nothing happening.
Tried to send a wrong URL just to see what's happening and I get an exception that URL is invalid but when I change the URL to a valid one, nothing happens.

```
    import java.io.IOException;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
    import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
    import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
    import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

    @Provider
    public class LoginFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
        @Context HttpServletRequest request;
        @Context HttpServletResponse response;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext arg0) throws IOException {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);

        if (session == null)
            response.sendRedirect("../../login.html");
    }

}
```